# Codeigniter mimic where_in() functionality with a simple where() statement

Tags: codeigniter

I have a method which can take a variable $where. This is then passed to a $this->db->where($where); statement.

I am trying to mimic the functionality of where_in() for one particular function.

I have a list of IDs in either array format or imploded string format.

I have tried passing `$where=array('blog.ID IN'=>'1,3');`

to the method to no avail.

This is causing `WHERE`blog`.`ID`IN '1,3'`
to be output instead of `WHERE`blog`.`ID`IN '1','3'`

Can anyone advise how i can use codeigniters where() function to mimic what its where_in() function does?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you can't use the actual `where_in()` method or just plain `query()`? Can you post the code for your method? I feel like there would be an easier way to do this....

Comment: I dont NEED to use the where() statement, it is just that the function is used by multiple contollers, and using the where() statements makes the code much more portable.. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$array = [1,3];
$where='blog.ID IN' . join(',', $array);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the array formatting you have utilized is, but none the less the above sadly does not work..

That outputs  WHERE `blog`.`ID` IN 1,3 , whereas I believe  WHERE `blog`.`ID` IN '1','3' is what is required... Thanks

Comment: OK, then maybe this: `$where='blog.ID IN \'' . join("','", $array) . '\'';
`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
function your_db_thingie($where)
{
    $this->db->select('*');

    if (is_array($where))
    {
        $this->db->where_in('field', $where);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('field', $where);
    }

    return $this->db->get('database');
}
```

Comment: In principle, great idea. but I am passing to the where function data as an array as well.

What i've done for now is passed data to the where_in function as a joined string, and then exploded it in the function back to an array.. but this is particularly inefficient..

Comment: Why don't you show the entire function, will be easier to come with suggestions then.